# Cancel signal (close connection) what could be the cause?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

In Kibana of our application, I keep seeing this line of log from `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions`:

```
[2f5e234b] Cancel signal (to close connection)
```

The thread is `reactor-http-epoll-1` or so.

It could happen in two situations:

- when the connection is successful and returns a response, then it does not matter
- when for some unknown cause, after 10 seconds, the connection does not return anything, and this line also happens, and period, nothing more. It seems to be a timeout but I am not sure(because the default timeout in my WebClient config is 10s)

What could be the cause of this? Client active drop or server active refusal?

Is the 2nd case a timeout? But not `TimeoutException()` is thrown afterwards.

I now do a `doOnCancel()` logging in WebClient to deal with the 2nd case, but then I notice there is case 1, and this `doOnCancel()` handling does not make sense anymore, because it seems to happen in all cases.

Comment: Did you have an explanation? because I have the same log...

Comment: Not yet, ticket in stand-by status in our backlog. I think it is client closing connection, because it happens either way.

Comment: found anything new? got the same issue after 60s, what's really strange is that I cannot reproduce this issue locally, it only happens inside a k8s pod

Comment: I think it is client closing the connection when getting data before timeout, or just when times out. For example for my webclient in Spring Boot, the default timeout is 5 seconds, and logs shows that the cancel signal happens after at most 5 sec.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ?

Comment: @angus as I said, no. We now ignore it, but suspect that it is the client(we ourselves) closing it, not the server, due to the timeout client config.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same log. But in my `WebClient` i returned `Mono.empty()` and the method signature was `Mono<Void>`.
After changing to `Mono<String>` the problem was gone.

Comment: Well, Mono.empty() is also Mono<T>. It's like your signature is Object but you return null. Is that what you wanted to say?

Comment: Method signature was Mono<Void>.